# The absolutely continuous representative of $t \mapsto (u(t), v(t))_{L^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u,v \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0)$ with $u_t, v_t \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$.

We know that
$$t \mapsto (u(t), v(t))_{L^2}$$
is absolutely continuous after a change on a set of measure zero.

Do we always identify the above function with the absolutely continuous representative?  What goes wrong if we don't?

Comment: The constant function $1$ on $[0,T]$ can be changed on the rationals (which is a set of measure $0$) so that the resulting function is not differentiable. If there's an absolutely continuous representative, then you want to use that one.